# Creating a Multi-Level Combobox in ASP/SQL

Tags: asp-classic

```
Table categories:
   id  
   name 
   parent_id
```

values

```
       1 - Main Category  - 0,
       2 - Main Category1 - 1,
       3 - Main category2 - 1,
       4 - Subcategory 1  - 2,
       5 - Subcategory 2  - 2
       6 - Main category3 - 1
```

Combobox Like this

```
Main Category 
     --> Main Category 1
     -------->SubCategory 1
     -------->SubCategory 2
     --> Main Category 2
     --> Main Category 3
```

How to ??? Thank for answer !

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are submitting form , you need to use javascript. A sample code is given below

```
cat1:<input type="checkbox" id="cat1"><br>

cat2:<input type="checkbox" id="cat2"  onChange="fnc('subcat1','subcat2')"><br>
subcat1:<input type="checkbox" id="subcat1" style="visibility:hidden"><br>
subcat2:<input type="checkbox" id="subcat2" style="visibility:hidden"><br>
cat3:<input type="checkbox" id="cat3">

<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(id1,id2)
{

if(document.getElementById("cat2").checked==true)
{
document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility='visible';
}
else
{
document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility='hidden';
}
}
</script>
```